# Excel query not removing row once deleted from source table with refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a source workbook that is an internal document, we want to share a "live" copy of a single sheet. I have created a new workbook and ran a query pulling data from that sheet. When I remove a row from the source data and refresh the query the deleted line does not disappear from the query. I have tried everything I know and can't get it to update and remove the row.

source data shows line removed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9vHX.jpg)

Query shows line is still there:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glknh.jpg)

Comment: There's probably an issue with your code. Perhaps if you edited your question to provide your data and code as text, someone might be able to assist you.